# How to convert from a VARCHAR to a DATE

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table tLogin with a field dateAdded set to a VARCHAR. The data in the record looks like this:

```
2012-09-21 15:51:38
```

Because the data is stored as VARCHAR I cannot perform date calculations on it.

I want to fix the problem by creating a new field tempDate which is set to a DATE, and convert the data from dateAdded into  field tempDate.
How can I copy all the data from dateAdded into tempDate? I don't mind losing the hours, minutes, and seconds when converting from dateAdded.

Comment: I tried the recommendation but none of them worked. Here's a sample error message: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),CONVERT(DATETIME,dateAdded),120)) 
FROM tLogin T' at line 2

Answer (score 1):

```
update t set t.tempDate = cast(t.dateAdded as datetime) from tLogin t
```

as Mr Jack suggests, the original code from me:

```
select cast('2012-09-21 15:51:38' as datetime)
```

Comment: You should also provide your initial suggestion so he realizes that maybe he doesnt need the extra column

Answer (score 0):

As long as the date/time are both in the varchar field, you should be able to simply use:

```
SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME, dateAdded) 
FROM tLogin
```

If you want to strip the timestamp off, you could do:

```
SELECT CONVERT(DATE,CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),CONVERT(DATETIME,dateAdded),120)) 
FROM tLogin
```

As an update:

```
UPDATE T 
SET tempDate = CONVERT(DATE,CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),CONVERT(DATETIME,dateAdded),120)) 
FROM tLogin T
```